# Executing Python scripts

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, virtualenv, execution

When reading [a Flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), the author asked me to `chmod a+x run.py` and then `./run.py`, rather than simply `python run.py` as I usually do. When I ignored the author's instruction and executed `python run.py`, I got an `ImportError`.(I suspect this error has something to do with `vitrualanv`.)

So my question is: What's the difference between

```
./run.py
```

and

```
python run.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your suspicion is correct. Notice how he creates a virtualenv called `flask`:

```
virtualenv flask
```

`run.py` contains the following:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

The first line is called a [`shebang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), in which the author defines that the python binary should be executed from `flask/bin/python`. If you instead execute `python run.py`, your system's default python binary is used. You could fix this by [*activating the virtualenv*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.8.2), by calling `source bin/activate`. Or by explicitly calling `flask/bin/python run.py`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first line of the file:

```
#!flask/bin/python
```

It means that running:

```
$ ./run.py
```

is equivalent to:

```
$ flask/bin/python run.py
```

and since flask/bin/python is in a virtual environment, it has different modules installed.